# Is there a selenium function for getting text on WebElements?(Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I’m using selenium(Python) with a chrome driver. I got a WebElement from a hotel site and I want to get it as a string. I used get_text but I get:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

How do I get text from a WebElement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always used the `textContent` or `innerText` attribute to get the text.

```
text = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_selector).textContent
OR
text = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_selector).innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `.text` on the received web element object, as following:

```py
text_value = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_locator).text
```

Of couse you can use any other approach to locate the element, not just by `CSS_SELECTOR`, this is just a sample code